# "Напрямую, через лужи" или "напрямую через лужи"?

Tags: пунктуация

Как будет правильно?

> Он направился к пивной напрямую через лужи.

или

> Он направился к пивной, напрямую, через лужи.

Answer (score 1):

The right version would be:

> Он направился к пивной напрямую, через лужи.

It's because in this particular case one can just say:

> Он направился к пивной через лужи.

That said, comma here separates `через` and `напрямую`. More specifically, it is clarification, it covered in ["Уточняющие члены предложения"](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118) in on of the most famous and de-facto used grammar references.

Keep in mind however, that unlike the spelling, punctuation is way less stricter and a lot of things depend on context and intonation. For instance, in this particular case one can think of "через лужи" not as a clarifying part (explaining what does exactly "напрямую" mean here) but as an integral part of the described direction. In that case it would be just "напрямую через лужи", without comma.

---

Коротко по-русски: если интонационно это уточнение, то запятая нужна. Напрямую - а как именно напрямую? - ну, через лужи. Если "через лужи" в данном случае логически составляет единое целое с "напрямую", то запятая не нужна.

Comment: Вот именно. Уточнение про уточнение необходимо: смысл немного меняется, но версия без запятых является абсолютно корректной. А потому начальное категоричное утверждение все же не вполне правильно.